# Windows AD user log on to Windows Service - User not visible in Local Users and Groups

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-services

I have a problem that I have not seen before. On a colleagues computer we tried to set up a windows service that should log on as his AD account. The service needs to access the AD users localdb `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` and therefore we normally connect with a local account. Can a AD user be used for this?

When he tried to log in with the AD account everything worked in the password prompt.

[image]

However when starting the service the error code below is thrown:

```
error 1068 the dependency service or group failed to start
```

The AD account is not visible in `Local Users and Groups` even though it says `Type Local` under Control Panel -> User Accounts. Can an AD account be connected to a local user to allow the account to log in to a windows service?

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: What services does this service depend on?

Comment: No other service, only databases and files in `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Comment: there isn't a DependOnService value under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\youservicename\

Comment: @HelpingHand Not what I can see. Added screenshot to question

Comment: If you vote down, please say why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a AD user be used for this?

Yes. Make sure the settings page actually *specifies* that it's an AD account, by using the full `DOMAIN\user` syntax (not just the plain username).

> The AD account is not visible in Local Users and Groups even though it says Type Local under Control Panel -> User Accounts

"Local" is not the account's type. It's the *profile folder's* type (after all, you're looking at a window that lists user profile folders). It's still an AD account but the user's *files* are stored on a local disk.

This is normal for an AD account. (The other possible mode would be a *roaming* profile – in which all of your files get downloaded from a server on login and uploaded back on logout. It's rather slow, and generally considered an obsolete feature by MS.)

> Can an AD account be connected to a local user

This makes no sense.

> to allow the account to log in to a windows service?

No, it has *nothing* to do with whether the account can log in as a Windows service. Your question is based on false assumptions.

The main thing that determines whether an account can log in as a Windows service is the local security policy (secpol.msc) – but the first time you configure an account like that, you get a popup saying that the account was automatically granted the right, so you shouldn't have to do anything extra. Whether it's a local account or an AD account should not generally matter.

> However when starting the service the error code below is thrown:
>
> ```
> error 1068 the dependency service or group failed to start
> ```

This doesn't really say that it's a problem with the account... But because what it *does* say doesn't match up with the reality (as you say in comments that the service has no dependencies), you should investigate deeper by checking the **Event Log (eventvwr.msc)**, which might have more verbose messages, perhaps even some from the service itself.

Make sure the username under red-painted areas has the domain-name in it (either the `DOMAIN\user` syntax or the `user@domain.tld` one). If neither is specified, the system will assume it's supposed to be a local username, which it won't be able to find.